# Join two tables with not exactly matching dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with dates that are about 1 month before the other table.

For example,
one table reports 1st quarter end on March 31st
and the other reports 1st quarter end on February 28th (or 29th)
but it would be perfectly fine to join them together by the date regardless that the two dates arent exactly the same.

Any suggestions, please.

Thanks

Comment: @MichaelCapobianco could be if you are using CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY. ANSI SQL is also introducing such capability, it's called LATERAL, Postgresql has plan on supporting that query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on DateDiff(dd, Date1, Date2) < x

Or to get more exact

```
select endOfMonth.*, begOfMonth.* 
from endOfMonth join begOfMonth 
on DATEADD (dd , 1 , endOfMonth.date ) = begOfMonth.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

If I rigthly understood you and you have the same number of column in those tables then you should use `UNION` in your SQL-query. See more information about `UNION` here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use the [DATEPART() function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp) that returns the `quarter` for any given date. Then you would be able to join on the returned quarter.

Sample SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER,date_column) AS t1_quarter
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER,date_column) AS t2_quarter
    FROM table2
) AS temp
WHERE temp.t1_quarter = temp.t2_quarter;
```

Put any other fields as you require (ID fields most probably) in the internal SELECTS.

Comment: Sql server has this function for quarter built in QUARTER([FIELD NAME])

Comment: I want to link the tables by their dates
select *
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.Date = t2.Date
but in my case for example,
t1.Date (for 1st quater end) is March 31st
and
t2.Date (for 1st quater end) is February 29th
but its okay to have the rest of the data from the tables aligned by the join

Comment: DATEPART(QUARTER) (please say QUARTER and not qq shorthand) does not align to your company's fiscal quarter, unless it happens to be Jan-Mar, Apr-Jun, etc. Typically this would require a calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

Your ON clause could look at year and quarter for a match:

```
ON TABLE1.YEAR([1st quarter end ]) = TABLE2.YEAR([1st quarter end ])
AND TABLE1.QUARTER([1st quarter end ]) = TABLE2.QUARTER([1st quarter end ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  val1 
From 
  Table1 T1 
  inner Join Table2 t2 
  on MONTH(T1.date1) = MONTH(t2.date1) 
  And YEAR(T1.date1) = YEAR(t2.date1)
```

Comment: This won't work for the example cited, since February <> March.